# How can I step through pictures in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I need to check all my pictures for a certain issue. Since this is a big document I do not want to scroll through all the text also. Is there a function to go to the next picture? I could of course use the input directory but sometimes there are more pictures in there that are no longer used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> and it'll show the `Go To` dialog for you.

In `Go to what` select `Graphic`.

In `Enter graphic number` enter:

- `+1` to go to the next picture
- any `n` number to go the `n`th picture

And finally click `next`

Answer (score 1):

You could click on References then insert a table of figures. This would allow you to jump straight to the inserted image.

[image: Screenshot of the table of figures in Microsoft Word]

You could then split the Word window to keep the list in view all the time. This link on the [Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/vertical-split-in-word-2010/51ac676e-9dbd-462a-9d59-a8121a9e891b) explains how to get a vertical split if you have a widescreen monitor.